# Apache MINA Server and PHP Client

Tags: java, php, nio, apache-mina

If I made a Apache MINA Server in Java and used a PHP Client would there be any problems? I do not quite understand the NIO thing so if you could explain that to me too I would <3 you :)

Comment: [We would <3 you if you elaborated a bit.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is terribly broad, but the short answer is yes, you should be able to setup mina <--> php.

I don't know that you really have to know all the nitty gritty details about Java NIO in order to use Mina. To my knowledge, that is sorta the point of Mina - it abstracts out the "hard parts" of the low level NIO stuff.

If you really want to learn about NIO I'm afraid there is no silver bullet answer here that will explain everything you need to know in order to effectively do networking programming - in any language in particular.

That being said, start with the basics, like the [wikipedia entry on sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket). Then try a tutorial on sockets in Java, PHP and whatever else you need. Read a book and\or take a class, etc, etc. This isn't one of those things that most people master via one stackoverflow post - it will take time and effort. Good luck!

Comment: I understand the details of I/O and Sockets but I just do not understand difference between NIO and the standard I/O.

Comment: I see. That is an entirely different question altogether :) There are some pretty big differences between regular sockets and NIO in java. You can start by checking out the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) but really I would suggest a good book. [This](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Sockets-Java-Second-Programmers/dp/0123742552) is the one that I read and it is really pretty "introductory" - I would highly recommend it. Good luck!